# `conda update --all` not updating Spyder

Tags: anaconda, spyder, conda

I just installed Anaconda on a Windows 10 machine and the first thing I did thereafter was go into the Anaconda Prompt and run `conda udpate conda` and then `conda update --all`. As expected, it updated a lot of stuff. When I then ran Spyder, however, I got a pop-up saying that a new version of Spyder was available.

What? I just updated everything. Checking `conda list` I see that `sypder 3.2.4` is indeed installed, so I do the following:

> (base) C:\Users\Mark>conda update --all
>
> Solving environment: done
>
> All requested packages already installed.
>
> (base) C:\Users\Mark>conda update spyder
>
> Solving environment: done
>
> Package Plan
>
> environment location: C:\Users\Mark\Anaconda3
>
> added / updated specs:
>       - spyder
>
> The following packages will be downloaded:
>
> ```
> package                    |            build
> ---------------------------|-----------------
> spyder-3.2.6               |           py36_0         2.6 MB
> ```
>
> The following packages will be UPDATED:
>
> ```
> spyder: 3.2.4-py36h8845eaa_0 --> 3.2.6-py36_0
> ```
>
> Proceed ([y]/n)?

Why is `conda update -all` not finding and updating my installed version of Spyder?

Comment: Sometimes a package down the chain of dependencies put a constraint on the rest and it doesn't allow to update them. Please don't worry too much about that.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Are you sure about this and how does that happen? It seems like a very arbitrary was on handling an `update --all`.

Comment: That was my experience, but `conda update --all` has improved in the last conda releases, so maybe it works better now.

Comment: I believe [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792095/why-does-conda-update-all-not-update-all) answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just updating spyder?

```
conda update spyder
```

Comment: Sure, that works, but it doesn't respond to the question. The point of `conda update --all` is that you don't have to go through package by package.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`conda update -n base conda`

Here, `base` is my current environment

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar behavior (on Linux) with conda, there it helped to be more specific:

```
conda update spyder=3.2.6
```

"NOTE: Conda updates to the highest version in its series, so Python 2.7 updates to the highest available in the 2.x series and 3.6 updates to the highest available in the 3.x series." 
[documentation conda](http://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html)

Comment: Thank you. That works, but it doesn't respond to the question. The point of `conda update --all` is that you don't have to go through package by package.

Comment: In which position are you working in? (Are you an Analyst?) The view AND the PARADIGM of a Web Development ( working with npm, ..) [which is the base of jupyter and influenced conda] is that you update all BUT only up to minor and major release NOT for NEW versions! -> the chance and so the RISK of getting into compatibility issues is too high. Thats why it isn't possible for every package (like it is the "standard" in web dev).

Comment: Check out the [documentation](https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-update.html). `--all  Update all installed packages in the environment.` If you run `conda update --all` and every installed package in the environment is not updated, then something is broken.

Comment: like I wrote, yes it updates all but only IN the version of a package -> major and minor. The HELP-documentation is right but not very specific. If you are looking further for documentation you will find "NOTE: Conda updates to the highest version in its series, so Python 2.7 updates to the highest available in the 2.x series and 3.6 updates to the highest available in the 3.x series." https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html