# Why does `conda update --all` not update all?

Tags: python, numpy, conda, geopandas

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48217641/conda-update-all-not-updating-spyder), but there's no answer there.

I installed `anaconda`, and then `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`. When I ran `import geopandas`, I got

```
>>> import geopandas as gpd
anaconda3/envs/gis/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: 
RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary 
incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88 
return f(*args, **kwds)
```

So, I tried updating all packages of my Anaconda env like `conda update --all`, but that didn't solve the warnings. What *did* solve it was updating the specific package: `conda update numpy`.

So, my question is: what does `conda update --all` do, that it doesn't update all packages?

Comment: Were you using any conda environments? One thing that could happen is that if you were in a conda environment which was using the global conda install of numpy I don't think a `conda update --all` would update anything.

Comment: It would be helpful to debug this if you could list the *exact* set of commands needed to try and reproduce it.

Answer (score 10):

The `conda update` documentation states that:

"This command accepts a list of package names and updates them to the latest versions *that are compatible with all other packages in the environment*." -- emphasis mine

This means that `conda update` will not update some packages if updating may put the stability of other packages at risk. As such, `conda update -all` is likely prioritizing stability over more recent builds. Whereas, `conda update numpy` is prioritizing the numpy update with minimal/no regard to overall stability.

As a side note, I have previously broken package stability for other installs doing exactly that -- updating a single package to its most recent version.