# Why doesn't Conda update --all update anything?

Tags: anaconda, environment-variables, conda

I accidentally installed two versions of Anaconda on Windows 10. One version under my user profile, the other into the windows program directory. I tried to resolve it by uninstalling both and then installing the intended version to my user profile.

After I reinstalled, conda update --all no longer updates packages. Prior to the reinstall I had updated a large number of packages using the same command.

It's possible that I was previously updating the wrong installation of Anaconda. If it helps, the user profile version is an older version of Anaconda (2019). The program files version (which I was intentionally removing) was a more recent version (2020). In my mind, the older version should have more updates available.

The reason I am jumping through these hoops is that the older version has been ok'd for work, but the newer versions have not (I accidentally broke the rules).

Here is what I get when I run the command conda update --all:

```
(base) C:\>conda update --all
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.
```

And here's what .condarc looks like:

```
ssl_verify: C:\Users\t57731\certs\ca-bundle.crt
channels:

  - defaults
  - conda-forge
```

Comment: This may help or give insight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53792095/why-does-conda-update-all-not-update-all

Comment: I don't think that it's a compatibility issue. I think it's related to reinstalling.  The reason being, before I reinstalled I successfully used the command. I reinstalled because I had two installs of Anaconda and I wanted to start from scratch.  I probably should add that to the original post.

Comment: I cleaned up my post a bit.

Comment: _Prior to the reinstall I had updated a large number of packages using the same command._ Was that in the `base` environment, too? It's best to avoid touching it as much as possible.